# no match for 'operator=' in ' when using std::map

Tags: c++

Compile error:

```
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp:243:2: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((CacheAssoc<SMPCacheState, unsigned int, false>*)this)->CacheAssoc<SMPCacheState, unsigned int, false>::previousTagHistoryMap = (operator new(24u), (<statement>, ((std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >*)<anonymous>)))'
```

If I'm understanding this correctly, it says I can't use the assignment operator. Why is that?

Header code:

```
template<class State, class Addr_t = uint32_t, bool Energy=false>
class CacheAssoc : public CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy> {
    //using XYZ classes
protected:
    std::map<uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t>> previousTagHistoryMap;
    //more stuff below
};
```

CPP code:

```
template<class State, class Addr_t, bool Energy>
CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::CacheAssoc(int32_t size, int32_t assoc, int32_t blksize, int32_t addrUnit, const char *pStr)
    : CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy>(size, assoc, blksize, addrUnit)
{
    //code
    previousTagHistoryMap = new std::map< uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t> >; //complains about this line
}
```

Entire compile results:

```
scons build/SMP_BOOKSIM/sesc.opt
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
SESC Simulator
Reading SConsopts
Building in /home/ud233user/sesc/build/SMP_BOOKSIM
Using variable in /home/ud233user/sesc/build_opts/SMP_BOOKSIM
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
 [     CXX] SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/cmp.cpp -> .o
 [     CXX] SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMPCache.cpp -> .o
In file included from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.h:424:0,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcore/GMemoryOS.h:32,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcore/GMemorySystem.h:28,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libmem/MemorySystem.h:30,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMemorySystem.h:26,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMPCache.h:26,
                 from build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMPCache.cpp:22:
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp: In constructor 'CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::CacheAssoc(int32_t, int32_t, int32_t, int32_t, const char*) [with State = SMPCacheState, Addr_t = unsigned int, bool Energy = false, int32_t = int]':
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp:197:9:   instantiated from 'static CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy>* CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy>::create(const char*, const char*, const char*, ...) [with State = SMPCacheState, Addr_t = unsigned int, bool Energy = false]'
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMPCache.cpp:136:48:   instantiated from here
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp:243:2: error: no match for 'operator=' in '((CacheAssoc<SMPCacheState, unsigned int, false>*)this)->CacheAssoc<SMPCacheState, unsigned int, false>::previousTagHistoryMap = (operator new(24u), (<statement>, ((std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >*)<anonymous>)))'
build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libsuc/CacheCore.cpp:243:2: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:253:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc> = std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:253:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >*' to 'const std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >&'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:268:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&&) [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc> = std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:268:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >*' to 'std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >&&'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:289:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >) [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc> = std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:289:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::map<unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > > >*' to 'std::initializer_list<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::list<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >'
scons: *** [build/SMP_BOOKSIM/libcmp/SMPCache.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
make: *** [sesc.opt] Error 2
```

Comment: Why `new`? Are you coming from a java or c# background?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. I'm modifying code in a very large C++ project. A bit overwhelming I must say. Is there a reason not to use `new`?

Comment: Well, usually you never use `new` in c++ code to create class instances. Just get rid of it.

Comment: In C#, all objects are references. In C++, objects are either values, references, pointers, left hand values, right hand values, universal references, ... the list goes on and on.  Because there is no garbage collector in C++, you are responsible for picking the right representation so that the object gets cleaned up at the right time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not assign to map object its pointer, use pointer in class declaration  for this purpose

```
template<class State, class Addr_t = uint32_t, bool Energy=false>
class CacheAssoc : public CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy> {
    //using XYZ classes
protected:
    std::map<uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t>>* previousTagHistoryMap;
    //more stuff below
```

than it will work correctly

```
template<class State, class Addr_t, bool Energy>
CacheAssoc<State, Addr_t, Energy>::CacheAssoc(int32_t size, int32_t assoc, int32_t blksize, int32_t addrUnit, const char *pStr)
    : CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy>(size, assoc, blksize, addrUnit)
{
    //code
    previousTagHistoryMap = new std::map< uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t> >; //complains about this line
}
```

do not forget about copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor, for proper memory management

**or simply do not use**

```
previousTagHistoryMap = new std::map< uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t> >; //complains about this line
```

instead `previousTagHistoryMap` already was created by default

and you do not suppose to do that

```
previousTagHistoryMap = new std::map< uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t> >;
```

because `previousTagHistoryMap` already exists

Comment: Are all protected/private/public variables supposed to be pointers?

Comment: Not all, and in this case we also can avoid them.

Comment: What's one approach to avoid them?

Comment: @Mykola Silly advice to use a pointer here. I see absolutely no reason to use one.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc You should not follow this. While this would technically solve your current problem, it's just not necessary to do so, and will complicate your implementation a lot to get it correct.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: read my answer closer. I wrote 2 aproaches to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of this code line

```
previousTagHistoryMap = new std::map< uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t> >;
```

The instance of `previousTagHistoryMap` is already present from your member declaration:

```
template<class State, class Addr_t = uint32_t, bool Energy=false>
class CacheAssoc : public CacheGeneric<State, Addr_t, Energy> {
     //using XYZ classes
protected:
     std::map<uint32_t, std::list<Addr_t>> previousTagHistoryMap;
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ An instance is automatically created on construction.
};
```

---

In general usage of `new` is avoided like hell in c++ code. There are either [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) classes, or [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that are used to do the dynamic memory allocation management for you (if actually needed).

Most of the time you just go with the [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) principle, that handles all of this from your call stack scope.

---

As you mentioned you're coming here from a java/c# background, where `new` is the standard way to obtain and initialize any instances of a class, c++ is different regarding this.

The former mentioned languages provide automatic garbage collection for instances going out of scope, where c++ doesn't provide such mechanism.

So for every `new`, you need to apply a balanced `delete` statement, which is error prone to handle correctly.

Well, as mentioned there are the container classes (as those you're using) or smart pointers, that do all of the hard to get stuff for you.

Comment: @hvd Of course, frickin' tablet auto correction it was ;-) THX 4 fixing.

Comment: Just for reference, I am modifying https://github.com/dilawar/sesc. It does `new` and `delete` technique you're warning against. I was just trying to stay consistent with the rest of the code.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Well, if that's a c++ port of something, it's just bad style to keep with `new`. Either do as I've recommended, or use c++ smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`previousTagHistoryMap` is not a pointer. You should not assign a pointer to it.

Comment: Well, while correct, just a bit of a narrow answer. What should OP do instead?  Do they need to do anything?